# Can my question about storing checkbox be opened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

Question Asked: [How should checklist be stored in the database from atomic point of view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998769/how-should-checklist-be-stored-in-the-database-from-atomic-point-of-view)

I would like to answer my own question, thoroughly, since I implemented my design and want to show pro and cons of both approach, non-normalized vs normalized approach.

The question was closed as duplicate but it is not really duplicate, it was not properly answered.

Comment: "There are multiple ways to answer it. I am just giving you insight what I am looking for but since I am asking, there might be a lot more than what I am looking for." - you seem to be arguing that it should be "opinion based" or "too broad" instead of duplicate... In any case some edit would go long way - i.e. if you'd explained why none of information in the duplicate is applicable to your "is comma separated values better"  sub-question.

Comment: The duplicate really does not answer my question, where as I asked for `implementation` while the dupicate is saying why CSV implementation is bad idea___ Disappointed I implemented the solution as was advised in the comments and I saw the problems first hand___I also discussed with a friend who advised me how to implement__all that can be answered with entire code that I have written.___I may improve question itself as well but just in the middle of so many things right now

Answer (score 12):

I believe the question is **both** "too broad" and "opinion based", and thus should not be reopened.

Let's look at the closing questions in the [post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSjup.png), copied verbatim here:

> My question is,
>
> 1. What is the best practice to implement checkboxes in database?
> 2. Is comma separated values better or a separate table for options? Does one provide more flexiblity down the road (eg. we want to add more companaies in option)
> 3. Is there any performance difference? What the normalized design show any enhancement, such as in search etc, that the other one does not have?

First, the question is actually not "a question" but "three questions". That's never a good sign.

The first two are firmly opinion and circumstance based and the third too broad, impossible to answer without adequate scope and constraints.

There is no advantage in reopening the question just to close it for different reasons.